# How to fix "SMS and CALL_LOG permission violation" on Google Play console for android apps

Tags: android, console, google-play, android-app-signing

We have removed the sms and call_log permissions. Here are the permissions we have on our app now
[image]

But still, we are getting the below interface on google play console

[image]

As 9th March is the deadline for this issue, we wanted to get this fixed immediately. Any help is appreciated

Comment: If you have ads in your app then that is why you still have that issue

Comment: We don't have any ads in the app

Comment: It is sure that the final apk doesnt have any SMS or CALL_LOG permissions. Please refer to the first image for permissions requested on play console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a Live chat with Google Play Support and resolved it.

The solution is as follows:

Create a new build (apk) and push it on to all visible sections to deactivate all the existing or old builds. I have pushed a new apk to below sections

1. Internal Testing
2. Alpha
3. Beta
4. Prod

**Note**: If you are not using sms or call log permissions, please select 
"***No, this release does not meet the SMS and Call Log permissions policy***".

Otherwise select
"***Yes, this release meets the SMS and Call Log permissions policy***" and provide with all specific details.

If you are not using these permissions, you should not be seeing this warning after uploading new build.

Comment: I no longer see this option in the permission declaration form "No, this release does not meet the SMS and Call Log permissions policy".

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue on the google play console.
If you sure that your final apk doesn't have any sensitive permission.
You must deactivate all previous apk that have sensitive permission on every track (internal, alpha, beta, production)

- You can view all existing activate apk on the Artifact library on the left side menu
- to deactivate previous apk, you must upload new apk and complete the  permission form by ticking “No, this release does not meet the SMS and Call Log permissions policy” on the form.

** I known it doesn't make sense that we need to tick "No, this release ....". But this is the instruction from google support and I also use the same method to solve it recently.